# Google Docs - Default layout when I create a new document

Tags: google-drive

I use Google Drive for work and work only.
I have a very particular protocol for pages I print. This is along the lines of:

1. Change the document to Verdana font face.
2. Put placeholder text on the first line
3. Center placeholder and change font size to 18pt
4. Put placeholder text on line 3
5. Insert a tab before the text above
6. Change all font other than the 18pt title to 12pt
7. Insert a footer
8. Set the font to 12pt Verdana
9. Align the footer body right
10. Populate line 1 of the footer with static text ('Work of {NAME},     {Division}')
11. Populate line 2 of the footer with today's date.
12. Populate line 3 with 'Page {PAGE_NUMBER} of {PAGE_TOTAL}' where the number and total characters are variable, offered by Google Docs for document footers.

I've read about Google scripts. How do I make it so that when I create a new document, the above layout is implemented?

Comment: You could also create a template and use that each time you want to create a new document: https://drive.google.com/templates?view=author Or do you really need this for old documents too?

Comment: I've manually implemented this in old docs. I'll accept it if you repost that as an answer; please do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For new documents you can use ready-made templates.
Google Docs has a [template system for new documents](https://drive.google.com/templates).

You can submit your own template and use it every time you want to create a document. Your own templates are [here](https://drive.google.com/templates?view=author) (and are public).

You can create a bookmark to your "Preview template"-link so it's easy to reach. You only need to click <kbd>Use this template</kbd>-button to create that document. If you have multiple templates you can use the link above to get to all your templates quickly.